# How can I highlight, by id number, using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I want select some text (highlight it yellow) with Greasemonkey. How can I do this by ID number?

Target page HTML:

```
<div class="answer" style="margin-top: 100px;">
<li id="l2289" onclick="sec(2289)" class="answer-sk">italya</li>
<li id="l2290" onclick="sec(2290)" class="answer-sk">Fransa</li>
<li id="l2291" onclick="sec(2291)" class="answer-sk">ingiltere</li>
<li id="l2292" onclick="sec(2292)" class="answer-sk">Portekiz</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, this question doesn't seem to have been asked before -- at least in the context of a Greasemonkey script.

To **highlight by ID on a static page**, merely set the CSS background.   Here's a **complete script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Highlite node with id l2290
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- Highlite the node with ID: l2290
var targNode = document.getElementById ("l2290");
targNode.style.background = "yellow";
```

You can [**see underlying code in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x4UrP/).
This code works in every modern, browser, userscript engine.

---

---

To **highlight by ID on a dynamic (AJAX driven) page**, requires polling or mutation observers, or AJAX intercepts.

The following script will work on most engines.  On Chrome, be sure to install the script using Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Highlite node with id l2290
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("#l2290", highlightNode);

function highlightNode (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("background", "yellow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the element by its ID and then reformat should work

```
document.getElementById('l2289').style.color = '#FFFF00';
```

Comment: This sets the *foreground* color. This is not the usual meaning/application of "highlighting".